# Count child nodes in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am creating an online ticket system where the tickets are pushed and displayed from Firebase. Is there a way to keep track of how many tickets there are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured out the answer myself later on.

```
  var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxx/");
  var ticketRef = ref.child("tickets");
  var count = 0;
  ticketRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   var newTicket = snapshot.val();
   count++;
  });
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to Frank Van Puffelen, it seems that using firebase's transaction function would be a better course.
[Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/5ESSp/)

Comment: good to hear that you solved your problem. Note that strictly speaking this doesn't increase a counter *in* Firebase. Instead is keeps a *client-side* count of the number of children. If that is what you needed, can you update the title (or do you mind if I update it) to indicate your requirement more clearly?

Comment: For my use, the client side counter was good enough but initially I wanted it to be at firebase. What I did was to get the count and then push/update the value to firebase. You may change the title as you fit necessary

Comment: If you need a server-side count (so inside your Firebase) have a look at the documentation for the transaction method. It has a good example for that IIRC.

Comment: Wow I tried transaction and that is considerably better! Thank you so much!

Comment: @NajmSheikh could you post the link of transaction? i m pretty struck at incrementing counter approach.  Random Values gets inserted as requests are pouring in.